# thread safe in iOS development

Tags: multithreading, ios, uikit, thread-safety

From wikipedia explanation about [thread-safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety),thread safe codes can be run in multithreads.

For iOS 3.x, UIKit is not thread safety, since [4.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009559-SW1), UIKIt is thread safety.

In our implementations, we can use synchronized to build thread safety codes. My questions about thread safety are:

1). How to detect thread safety coding issue with instruments tools or other ways ?
2). Any good practices to write thread safety codes for iOS development ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102797/when-do-i-need-to-worry-about-thread-safety-in-an-ios-application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702013/drawing-in-a-background-thread-on-ios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> since 4.0, UIKIt is thread safety.

Basically, UIKit is not thread-safe. Only **drawing to a graphics context in UIKit** is thread-safe since 4.0.

1) Hmm, I also want to know about that :-)

2) How about [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Answer (score 1):

To make a non thread-safe object thread safe, consider using a proxy (see the code below). I use it for example for NSDateFormatter, which is not a thread safe class, when parsing data in a background thread.

```
/**
 @brief
 Proxy that delegates all messages to the specified object
 */
@interface BMProxy : NSProxy {
    NSObject *object;
    BOOL threadSafe;
}

@property(atomic, assign) BOOL threadSafe;

- (id)initWithObject:(NSObject *)theObject;
- (id)initWithObject:(NSObject *)theObject threadSafe:(BOOL)threadSafe;

@end

@implementation BMProxy

@synthesize threadSafe;

- (id)initWithObject:(NSObject *)theObject {
    object = [theObject retain];
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithObject:(NSObject *)theObject threadSafe:(BOOL)b {
    if ((self = [self initWithObject:theObject])) {
        self.threadSafe = b;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    return [object methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
    if (self.threadSafe) {
        @synchronized(object) {
            [anInvocation setTarget:object];
            [anInvocation invoke];
        }
    } else {
        [anInvocation setTarget:object];
        [anInvocation invoke];
    }
}

- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    BOOL responds = [super respondsToSelector:aSelector];
    if (!responds) {
        responds = [object respondsToSelector:aSelector];
    }
    return responds;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [object release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Turn this into a category on `NSObject`. };)